# Android Widgets: How to add Views to RemoteViews on runtime

Tags: android, textview, widget, remoteview

I want to add text views arranged in a linear layout to my widget on runtime.   I do following:

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(context);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    TextView t = new TextView(context);
    t.setText("Hello");
    l.addView(t);  }        
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews (context.getPackageName(), l.getId());
views.addView(R.layout.main, view);
```

But when I add widget I get a Problem loading widget error. Seems like `RemoteViews` has a problem with receiving a constructed view id as a parameter. But I can't make a reference to XML resource, because they are created on runtime. What is the proper way to populate the `RemoteViews` with `TextViews` on runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only xml resources can be used in RemoteViews. Views created on runtime should be based on predefined xml views.